# is there any possibility to read struct via interface from deployed contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, struct, interfaces

the contract is deployed which has no view function for that particular struct, is there any way to read values via interface in another contract which I want to write and deploy ?

Comment: There is nothing which represents a "struct" during runtime. This concept exists only during compilation. After you deploy your contract, there may be variables (local or state) which are instances of this struct. So your question should be - "is there a way to read a state-variable?". And for the sake of this question, the type of this variable (struct or other) doesn't even matter. The answer is Yes if the variable was declared `public`, and No otherwise.

Comment: To be more accurate - No, not via an interface. You could read the blockchain and parse it in order to find the value of every state-variable.

Comment: and for public struct variables you will need the ABIEncoderv2: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.6/layout-of-source-files.html#abiencoderv2.